# AppFabric Local Cache Performance

Tags: asp.net, caching, appfabric

I'm currently testing out AppFabric Distributed Cache, it's been working great.

When performance testing the Local Cache feature however, I find there is no difference in performance.

For the purposes of the performance test I am storing large pages generated from OutputCache into AppFabric and am noticing the same performance with or without local cache on.

Does anyone else have any similar experience?

I'm using Timeout based local cache, with a ttl of 300 and objectcount of 100000.

Comment: Are you sure that the results aren't being served out of the .Net cache before they get to the AppFabic layer?

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail on what you're doing, may be with some code? I'm not sure I understand what you're doing with output caching!

Answer (score 3):

If the distributed cache is on the local server, then there should be very little difference.Since the main time usage accessing the distributed cache is the transport across the network.

It may be that it takes a bit longer to access the distributed cache than the local on the same machine, since local cache is in process:

> When local cache is enabled, the cache client stores a reference to
>   the object locally. This keeps the object active in the memory of the
>   client application

However, local cache does add some sync overhead. So the actual differences will depend on your usage pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might depend on the type of data your are caching.

We use local cache a lot for web services that have many almost identical Get methods (small data in return). The local cache gave a significant less load on the cache servers, and most transactions take 0 ms.